# Select Parcels by Street Geometry

Tags: arcgis-server, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I'm trying to select the parcels near a street with web adf for vb.net, does anyone know how to do that? I have a graphics resource in the map resources with the selected streets and I need to do the buffer with all the geometry in that resource and get the parcels around.

Can I use a spatialFilter? How can I get the geometry in the Graphics Resource?

Comment: Hey Mendoza, which programming language are you using?

Comment: hi, i'm using visual basic .net, framework 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a Model in ArcGIS Desktop which does a select by location with a buffer distance set. Then adding a Tool layer to the Map Service and publishing the geoprocessing model as a service. Then in the Web ADF you can just pick up the existing service.

In saying this another way to go is to use this sample from the Esri Website to point you in the right direction as far as the coding goes.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0002000000wp000000

Hope this helps,

CDB

Comment: Please use a gp service do do this as the fine grained web adf stuff is highly complicated.